# The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process when deleting a file

Tags: c#, image, ioexception

When I try to delete a file, it says that it is being used by my server so I tried implementing a `using (Image img = Image.FromFile(imgFilePath))` but then I got `parameter is not valid` error message. I've also tried storing the image in a variable then calling `.Dispose()` but that didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Delete code (client side):

```
private void pbDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (imgSliderCapture.Images.Count > 0)
            {
                int currentImageIndex = imgSliderCapture.CurrentImageIndex;
                m_DispenseOrderPresenter.DeleteCapturedRxImage(currentImageIndex);
                imgSliderCapture.Images.RemoveAt(currentImageIndex);

                if (imgSliderCapture.Images.Count <= 0)
                {
                    pbCamera.Image = global::KeyCentrix.RxKey.UI.Properties.Resources.white_camera;
                    pbCamera.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
                    imgSliderCapture.ImageList = null;
                    pbCamera.Padding = new Padding(38, 15, 40, 35);
                    pbCamera.Size = new Size(169, 123);
                    pbDelete.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }

public void DeleteCapturedRxImage(int currentImageIndex)
        {
            if (File.Exists(m_PathImagePairs[currentImageIndex].Key))
            {
                File.Delete(m_PathImagePairs[currentImageIndex].Key);
            }
        }
```

Server side code I think maybe causing the problem:

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string, Image>> GetCapturedRxImages(string rxId)
        {
            try
            {                 
                string[] imgFilePaths = GetCapturedRxImagesFilePaths(rxId);
                List<KeyValuePair<string, Image>> images = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Image>>();
                List<byte[]> byteArrays = new List<byte[]>();

                if (imgFilePaths == null || imgFilePaths.Length < 1)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                foreach(string imgFilePath in imgFilePaths)
                {
                    images.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Image>(imgFilePath, Image.FromFile(imgFilePath)));
                }
                return images;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogFactory.LogEvent(typeof(RxDirSvc), LogLevel.Error, String.Format("Exception in {0}", MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()), ex);
                return null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the user captured drug's image file name and path
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="identifier"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string[] GetCapturedRxImagesFilePaths(string rxId)
        {
            try
            {
                List<string> filesFound = new List<string>();
                string pathFolder = Directory.GetParent(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath) + @"\images\RxCapturedImages\" + rxId;
                
                filesFound.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(pathFolder, "*.jpeg"));
                return filesFound.ToArray();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogFactory.LogEvent(typeof(RxDirSvc), LogLevel.Error, String.Format("Exception in {0}", MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()), ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the client side app running on the server too? Does the server do any processing of these images it loads, or would loading then as a byte array work for what it needs?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes the application runs on the server but the server doesn't do any processing of the images, just grabbing and returning the list of images as key value pairs. Would loading the images as byte arrays help to prevent the error? Or is that so that I can use the using statement?

Comment: Any time that you use Image.FromFile the file will be locked until the Image is disposed, but as you seem to be saying that you just load the image and send them to the client then I'd say on the server side you definitely should just be loading bytes and shipping them; it's up to the client if it wants to make an Image out of them

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this way? You have to remove the image first from the list and then delete it. The error may have occurred since the image is still bound to the slider.

```
imgSliderCapture.Images.RemoveAt(currentImageIndex);
m_DispenseOrderPresenter.DeleteCapturedRxImage(currentImageIndex);
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that in the original post! I did try it that way as well but it still seemed to error out, unfortunately